# Firebase Cloud Messaging,Can not add the Plugin 'com.google.gms.google-services' to gradle in android Studio

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

While adding the Plugin ie. `apply plugin:'com.google.gms.google-services'` to the android app level gradle, I'm getting the error like

```
No such property: applicationVariants for class: java.lang.String
```

I had followed all the steps that had given to the firebase console  but still getting the same error. I had added all the dependencies to app level gradle and class path to Project-level gradle.

Did lots of searches in google but no hope.

Comment: you must update play services in android studio

Comment: i am using the latest ones such as com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.4.0, com.google.android.gms:play-services-appinvite:9.4.0 etc

Comment: go in sdk and update play services version first

Comment: for that no updates found , using the latest one

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line in your project gradle(not module app gradle) depedenciy
 classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'